# Use emoji in Github markdown

Tags: github, markdown, emoji

I am generating a GitHub comment using their API, by passing a markdown in the body as follows

```
{
  "body": "Component \n | --------\n ![alt text](https://static.wooicon.com/files/a/rr/ow/cd50f73a0f0a769fcb10138d4f8eb98b/arrow-down.png)",
  "commit_id": "8574ac234999ffb5bbf93f66fac30a84342fe396",
  "path": "README.md",
  "position": 4
}
```

I am now looking to use emojis from [this](https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908) page to use instead of the image URL above.

I did try passing in just the emoji as follows

```
"body": "Component \n | --------\n ![alt text](:small_red_triangle_down:)",
```

However, that did not seem to work, and did not render an image. Please advise how I can use emoji in GitHub markdown.

Answer (score 0):

That might not be still supported, considering that the GitHub API does mention emoji in [pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) and [issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#list-events-for-a-repository), but... using `application/vnd.github.symmetra-preview+json` as  a custom [media type](https://developer.github.com/v3/media) in the `Accept` header.

You can try that same media type. However, that was in [beta last February (2018)](https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-02-22-label-description-search-preview/).

The [OP Kevin Chau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10752398/kevin-chau) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643622/use-emoji-in-github-markdown#comment94182668_53645396):

> I was able to use in code, by just concatenating  to the markdown, and using the header **`application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json`**

Comment: thanks for getting back. I was able to use in code, by just concatenating  to the markdown, and using the header application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json